# Wrong Title tags text in facebook wall preview

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

When I paste my website URL in facebook wall. In the iframe's page title. I am seeing some strange title text instead of reading index.php title tag. I am not getting from where this text is coming.

When we post website url in facebook, which page will be load in iframe.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your open graph tags. Full info here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

There is also a test tool that allows you to debug what information facebook is looking at when it sees your page, here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug